# How do I determine if highlight/underline in EditText is from autocomplete

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I have a custom view that extends EditText that has ToggleButtons for rich text editing. If I allow autocomplete, which I want to do, the indicator for the current word triggers my detection for style spans.

For example on most devices the autocorrect eligible word is an underline. As you type I have a text watcher that keeps track of the current styles that are applied to the text and adds new spannables if the user toggles a style button. This ends up detecting the underline and turning the toggle on.

I can write code to check if the underline toggle was set before we found the span. (I would actually need to do this for all my styles really since some devices use a background color to indicate the current autocorrect word.) But I'm unsure what I would use to trigger turning the toggle back to off. Check if they typed space? What happens when you select a suggested word?

Has anyone done this? Is there a way to ask if the span is from autocomplete or any other notifications to know the OS drew the span?

Comment: If you generate all the style spans yourself (except for the autocomplete one), then why not add something like a flag/id to them? Only for the spans containing such a flag/id you then toggle the relevant `ToggleButton`(s). Spans without it are system-generated and should thus be ignored. I'd probably create simple subclasses for all spans to accomplish this, or some sort of proxy/wrapper.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't generate them all myself.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how the spans get generated? I'd be interested to see where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just now I had a similar problem, namely eliminating the unwanted underline before converting the spans into HTML.  I found the answer in the source to `TextView`.

There is a method `TextView#clearComposingText()` that will remove all styles applied by the IME during autosuggest, preserving all other styles.  You could likely call it after every user keystroke, which would remove the underlines.

Hope this helps someone.